# merge list of dataframes by and sum different columns

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, plyr, reduce

I have a list of dataframes

```
> df.t
[[1]]
column_A start_B stop_C column_D column_E
1        0        23       2        3 
1        23       200      1        0
2        0        55       0        1
[[2]]
column_A start_B stop_C column_D column_E
1        0        200      1        0
2        0        20       2        0
2        20       55       0        1
[[3]]
column_A start_B stop_C column_D column_E
1        0        200      0        0
2        0        55       4        2
```

I want to split based on column_A, and merge by the column_A, start_B and stop_C and sum column_D and column_E. For each unique column_A element, I want to find all the possible unique range combinations using only a unique start_B and stop_C element. For example where column_A = 1, the unique lowest to highest range between start_B and stop_C is 0 - 200, however, df.t[[1]] has broken this range from 0 - 23 then 23-200. leading to this expected output after merging

expected output:

```
> df.merge

column_A start_B stop_C column_D column_E
1        0        23       3        3
1        23       200      2        0   
2        0        20       6        3
2        20       55       4        4
```

I know in order to split and merge just two of the dataframes I can do:

```
lst1 <- split(df.t[[1]], df.t[[1]]$column_A)
lst2 <- split(df.t[[2]], df.t[[2]]$column_A

require(survival)

df <- do.call(rbind, mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {

    x$event <- y$event <- 0
    lst1.spl <- survSplit(x, cut=y$stop_C, start='column_A', end='start_B', event='event')
    lst2.spl <- survSplit(y, cut=x$stop_C, start='column_A', end='start_B', event='event')
    mrg <- merge(lst1.spl, lst2.spl, 
            by=c('column_A', 'start_B', 'stop_C'))
    mrg[c('column_A', 'start_B', 'stop_C', 'column_D', 'column_E')]
    },
lst1, lst2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```

However to complete this on a list of dataframes and sum column_D and column_E I think I should use reduce(), however I am not sure if it is either possible or the best method!

```
df.merge = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by=c('column_A', 'start_B', 'stop_C')), df.t)
```

This only merges by the first three columns and does not sum column_D and column_E. I know I should use ddply, however I am not sure how to correctly use it with reduce.

Thank you!

Comment: Here `df.merge` I guess is the one you got after `Reduce(` or is it the expected output?

Comment: perhaps without join and with `dplyr` `df <- Reduce(rbind, df.t) %>% group_by(column_A, column_B, column_C) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum), column_D, column_E)`

Comment: @ckluss Your code gives slightly different result than the expected

Comment: @user3324491 Are you sure the expected results are correct based on your input `df.t`?  It is not clear how you got `23` in `column_B`

Comment: I guess I'm still not understanding how you get to the output you've listed. A few questions: (1) What do you mean by "split based on column_A"? Do you mean R's `split` function? But that wouldn't change the merge result. (2) Just for an example, can you explain how you get a 4 in row 4 of `column_D`? (3) Why are some combinations of values in the three merge columns missing from your expected output? For example, what happened to 1, 0, 200?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the split function and split up column_A, and I would like to merge by and produce all the possible outcomes for column_B and column_C from one single lowest column_B number ranging to one highest column_C number. So where column_A = 1, df.t[[2]] is 0, 200 but df.t[[1]] has two rows, one ranging from 0, 23, then from 23 to 200. So merging with the possible combinations for the range of 0-200 will give us 1, 0, 23 and 1, 23, 200.

Comment: The sum will be between the range of  0 - 23 and 23 - 200, which is how 4 in row 4 of column_D is produced because df.t[[3]] between 0 to 55 has a score of 4, this is encompassed in the region between 20 to 55. I will edit the question to reflect this as I have not clearly explained it.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output doesn't seem consistent with your description of what you're trying to do. Here's some code that will give you the some of column_D and the sum of column_E for each combination of the column_A, column_B, and column_C in the three data frames. If I've misunderstood your goal, please let me know and I'll update.

Method: Combine the three data frames into a single data frame, then split the data by the three grouping columns and sum over each group.

```
library(dplyr) 

# Combine all three data frames into a single data frame
alldfs = bind_rows(df.t)

# Sum column_D and column_E for each combination of the grouping columns
alldfs %>% group_by(column_A, column_B, column_C) %>%
  summarise(sum_column_D = sum(column_D),
            sum_column_E = sum(column_E))

  column_A column_B column_C sum_column_D sum_column_E
1        1        0       23            2            3
2        1        0      200            1            0
3        1       90      200            1            0
4        2        0       20            2            0
5        2        0       55            4            3
6        2       20       55            0            1
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that I want to merge only after splitting on column_A first. I will update the question. Thanks